# How to remove line? [Help with CTF]

Tags: ida, assembly

[image]

Hi!
So, the program print me a `Flag length is 32`. As I understand `call strlen` convert my flag to string of length. So, I want to remove that part `call strlen` or somehow avoid it (maybe I'm not right at all, because I really bad in assembly and RE, it's my first CTF and what are your options)

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. So you want to patch the binary? In IDA you first need to enable the respective menu item. Alternatively you can use other tools to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `call strlen` to `call printf` and got my flag. I am so happy and proud of myself.